# Show user popup/modal and perform navigation to different pages beneath while user is still presented popup/modal on top (Xamarin Forms)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, modal-dialog, popup

I'm trying to achieve solution stated in title. I'm trying to implement iOS 3D touch shortcuts and i want to perform some navigation behind popup/model after user has authenticated with biometric/pin. I want to perform navigation to recreate navigation stack. I can't just open view without recreating it.

For modal i don't think it will work but maybe poup is solution. I'm using Rg.plugin.popup package. From what i've read i should be able to perform navigation and popup shouldn't disappear. For me it closes once i perform navigation.

Do you know if what im trying to achieve is doable with popup/modal? Or you maybe have another idea how to recreate navigation stack from code without user interaction?